# How can I use LibTooling/Clang in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, clang, llvm-clang, libtooling

I'm trying to use LibTooling to replace function and variable names in C-code files. Thus I downloaded llvm and followed the instructions to set it up in windows using GMake and Visual Studio 2015.

There are many tutorials (e.g. [this one](https://kevinaboos.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/clang-tutorial-part-ii-libtooling-example/)) which I'd like to follow, but they all assume that you are using Linux/Make, so they provide a Makefile which somehow manages the integration into the llvm source code.

What I want to do is use these examples in Visual Studio, but I don't know where to begin - can I just create a new project inside the given (llvn.sln) solution and add the code there? How do I tell Visual Studio to include the clang sources (as defined in those Makefiles I mentioned)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Environment:Windows 10 X64,VS2017,CMake 3.9.3
References:
https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html

Create a working directory,like D:\software\LLVM

Download LLVM and Clang source code(version 6.0.0):

http://releases.llvm.org/6.0.0/llvm-6.0.0.src.tar.xz
http://releases.llvm.org/6.0.0/cfe-6.0.0.src.tar.xz

extract them in working directory,and rename them to llvm and clang(remove version codes):

```
D:\software\LLVM\llvm

D:\software\LLVM\clang
```

if you keep the version code in the folder name,then later CMake will say can't find folder "clang"

create a build output directory under working directory,like:

```
D:\software\LLVM\build-x86
```

and for x64(only if you need x64 build):

```
D:\software\LLVM\build-x64
```

get into the build output directory:

```
cd D:\software\LLVM\build-x86
```

run cmake,for x86 build:

```
cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A Win32 -Thost=x64 ..\llvm
```

for x64 build:

```
cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A x64 -Thost=x64 ..\llvm
```

Note: It's better to only enable the target that your clang need to support, or the build process will be very slow. To only build the targets that your clang will support,use

```
-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=target_list
```

for example:

```
-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86;ARM"
```

The list of all targets seems to be in:

```
D:\software\LLVM\llvm\bindings\python\llvm\disassembler.py
```

they are:

```
_targets = ['AArch64', 'ARM', 'Hexagon', 'MSP430', 'Mips', 'NVPTX', 'PowerPC', 'R600', 'Sparc', 'SystemZ', 'X86', 'XCore']
```

So X86 seems to include both x86 and x64.

CMake will product a VS solution file:

```
D:\software\LLVM\build-x86\LLVM.sln
```

open it with VS2017,and you only need to build the sub group "Clang libraries",my build is the default Debug build.

Now the reference is https://kevinaboos.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/clang-tutorial-part-ii-libtooling-example/
but the code in that page is for older version of LLVM so it won't compile.

Here is the working code with LLVM6.0.0:

create a C++ console application in VS2017.

get into debug/x86 configuration.

in project properties dialog,for debug/win32 config,

modify "Disable Specific Warnings" to:

```
4146
```

modify "Additional Include Directories" to:

```
D:\software\LLVM\clang\include;D:\software\LLVM\llvm\include;D:\software\LLVM\build-x86\include;D:\software\LLVM\build-x86\tools\clang\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

modify "Additional Library Directories" to:

```
D:\software\LLVM\build-x86\Debug\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)
```

modify "Additional Dependencies" to:

```
Mincore.lib;clangAnalysis.lib;clangARCMigrate.lib;clangAST.lib;clangASTMatchers.lib;clangBasic.lib;clangCodeGen.lib;clangCrossTU.lib;clangDriver.lib;clangDynamicASTMatchers.lib;clangEdit.lib;clangFormat.lib;clangFrontend.lib;clangFrontendTool.lib;clangHandleCXX.lib;clangIndex.lib;clangLex.lib;clangParse.lib;clangRewrite.lib;clangRewriteFrontend.lib;clangSema.lib;clangSerialization.lib;clangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.lib;clangStaticAnalyzerCore.lib;clangStaticAnalyzerFrontend.lib;clangTooling.lib;clangToolingASTDiff.lib;clangToolingCore.lib;clangToolingRefactor.lib;libclang.lib;LLVMAArch64AsmParser.lib;LLVMAArch64AsmPrinter.lib;LLVMAArch64CodeGen.lib;LLVMAArch64Desc.lib;LLVMAArch64Disassembler.lib;LLVMAArch64Info.lib;LLVMAArch64Utils.lib;LLVMAMDGPUAsmParser.lib;LLVMAMDGPUAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMAMDGPUCodeGen.lib;LLVMAMDGPUDesc.lib;LLVMAMDGPUDisassembler.lib;LLVMAMDGPUInfo.lib;LLVMAMDGPUUtils.lib;LLVMAnalysis.lib;LLVMARMAsmParser.lib;LLVMARMAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMARMCodeGen.lib;LLVMARMDesc.lib;LLVMARMDisassembler.lib;LLVMARMInfo.lib;LLVMARMUtils.lib;LLVMAsmParser.lib;LLVMAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMBinaryFormat.lib;LLVMBitReader.lib;LLVMBitWriter.lib;LLVMBPFAsmParser.lib;LLVMBPFAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMBPFCodeGen.lib;LLVMBPFDesc.lib;LLVMBPFDisassembler.lib;LLVMBPFInfo.lib;LLVMCodeGen.lib;LLVMCore.lib;LLVMDebugInfoCodeView.lib;LLVMDebugInfoMSF.lib;LLVMDemangle.lib;LLVMGlobalISel.lib;LLVMHexagonAsmParser.lib;LLVMHexagonCodeGen.lib;LLVMHexagonDesc.lib;LLVMHexagonDisassembler.lib;LLVMHexagonInfo.lib;LLVMInstCombine.lib;LLVMInstrumentation.lib;LLVMipo.lib;LLVMIRReader.lib;LLVMLanaiAsmParser.lib;LLVMLanaiAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMLanaiCodeGen.lib;LLVMLanaiDesc.lib;LLVMLanaiDisassembler.lib;LLVMLanaiInfo.lib;LLVMLinker.lib;LLVMMC.lib;LLVMMCDisassembler.lib;LLVMMCParser.lib;LLVMMipsAsmParser.lib;LLVMMipsAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMMipsCodeGen.lib;LLVMMipsDesc.lib;LLVMMipsDisassembler.lib;LLVMMipsInfo.lib;LLVMMSP430AsmPrinter.lib;LLVMMSP430CodeGen.lib;LLVMMSP430Desc.lib;LLVMMSP430Info.lib;LLVMNVPTXAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMNVPTXCodeGen.lib;LLVMNVPTXDesc.lib;LLVMNVPTXInfo.lib;LLVMObject.lib;LLVMOption.lib;LLVMPowerPCAsmParser.lib;LLVMPowerPCAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMPowerPCCodeGen.lib;LLVMPowerPCDesc.lib;LLVMPowerPCDisassembler.lib;LLVMPowerPCInfo.lib;LLVMProfileData.lib;LLVMScalarOpts.lib;LLVMSelectionDAG.lib;LLVMSparcAsmParser.lib;LLVMSparcAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMSparcCodeGen.lib;LLVMSparcDesc.lib;LLVMSparcDisassembler.lib;LLVMSparcInfo.lib;LLVMSupport.lib;LLVMSystemZAsmParser.lib;LLVMSystemZAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMSystemZCodeGen.lib;LLVMSystemZDesc.lib;LLVMSystemZDisassembler.lib;LLVMSystemZInfo.lib;LLVMTableGen.lib;LLVMTarget.lib;LLVMTransformUtils.lib;LLVMVectorize.lib;LLVMX86AsmParser.lib;LLVMX86AsmPrinter.lib;LLVMX86CodeGen.lib;LLVMX86Desc.lib;LLVMX86Disassembler.lib;LLVMX86Info.lib;LLVMX86Utils.lib;LLVMXCoreAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMXCoreCodeGen.lib;LLVMXCoreDesc.lib;LLVMXCoreDisassembler.lib;LLVMXCoreInfo.lib;
```

because I can't find information about which library to include ,I include all libraries in D:\software\LLVM\build-x86\Debug\lib,plus Mincore.lib

Here is a C# code to generate the lib references:

```
static void buildLLVMLibList()
{
    string s = "";
    foreach (string fn in Directory.GetFiles(
        //@"D:\software\LLVM\build-x64\Debug\lib"
        @"D:\software\LLVM\build-x86\Debug\lib"
        , "*.lib"))
    {
        s += new FileInfo(fn).Name + ";";
    }
    return;//break here
}
```

modify pch.h to:

```
#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H

// TODO: add headers that you want to pre-compile here
// Declares clang::SyntaxOnlyAction.
#include "clang/Frontend/FrontendActions.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/Tooling.h"
// Declares llvm::cl::extrahelp.
#include "llvm/Support/CommandLine.h"

#include "clang/Driver/Options.h"
#include "clang/AST/AST.h"
#include "clang/AST/ASTContext.h"
#include "clang/AST/ASTConsumer.h"
#include "clang/AST/RecursiveASTVisitor.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/ASTConsumers.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/FrontendActions.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/Tooling.h"
#include "clang/Rewrite/Core/Rewriter.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace clang;
using namespace clang::driver;
using namespace clang::tooling;
using namespace llvm;

#endif //PCH_H
```

modify main cpp file to:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>



Rewriter rewriter;
int numFunctions = 0;
llvm::cl::OptionCategory MyToolCategory("my-tool options");

class ExampleVisitor : public RecursiveASTVisitor<ExampleVisitor> {
private:
    ASTContext *astContext; // used for getting additional AST info

public:
    explicit ExampleVisitor(CompilerInstance *CI)
        : astContext(&(CI->getASTContext())) // initialize private members
    {
        rewriter.setSourceMgr(astContext->getSourceManager(),
            astContext->getLangOpts());
    }

    virtual bool VisitFunctionDecl(FunctionDecl *func) {
        numFunctions++;
        string funcName = func->getNameInfo().getName().getAsString();
        if (funcName == "do_math") {
            rewriter.ReplaceText(func->getLocation(), funcName.length(), "add5");
            errs() << "** Rewrote function def: " << funcName << "\n";
        }
        return true;
    }

    virtual bool VisitStmt(Stmt *st) {
        if (ReturnStmt *ret = dyn_cast<ReturnStmt>(st)) {
            rewriter.ReplaceText(ret->getRetValue()->getLocStart(), 6, "val");
            errs() << "** Rewrote ReturnStmt\n";
        }
        if (CallExpr *call = dyn_cast<CallExpr>(st)) {
            rewriter.ReplaceText(call->getLocStart(), 7, "add5");
            errs() << "** Rewrote function call\n";
        }
        return true;
    }
};


class ExampleASTConsumer : public ASTConsumer {
private:
    ExampleVisitor *visitor; // doesn't have to be private

public:
    // override the constructor in order to pass CI
    explicit ExampleASTConsumer(CompilerInstance *CI)
        : visitor(new ExampleVisitor(CI)) // initialize the visitor
    { }

    // override this to call our ExampleVisitor on the entire source file
    virtual void HandleTranslationUnit(ASTContext &Context) {
        /* we can use ASTContext to get the TranslationUnitDecl, which is
             a single Decl that collectively represents the entire source file */
        visitor->TraverseDecl(Context.getTranslationUnitDecl());
    }

};



class ExampleFrontendAction : public ASTFrontendAction {
public:

    void EndSourceFileAction() override {
        llvm::outs() << "END OF FILE ACTION:\n";
        rewriter.getEditBuffer(rewriter.getSourceMgr().getMainFileID()).write(errs());
    }

    virtual std::unique_ptr<ASTConsumer> CreateASTConsumer(CompilerInstance &CI, StringRef file) {
        return  std::unique_ptr<ASTConsumer>(new ExampleASTConsumer(&CI)); // pass CI pointer to ASTConsumer
    }
};


extern llvm::cl::OptionCategory MyToolCategory;

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    // parse the command-line args passed to your code
    CommonOptionsParser op(argc, argv, MyToolCategory);
    // create a new Clang Tool instance (a LibTooling environment)
    ClangTool Tool(op.getCompilations(), op.getSourcePathList());

    // run the Clang Tool, creating a new FrontendAction (explained below)
    int result = Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory<ExampleFrontendAction>().get());

    errs() << "\nFound " << numFunctions << " functions.\n\n";
    // print out the rewritten source code ("rewriter" is a global var.)

    std::cin.get();
    return result;
}
```

Then create a testC++ file,like:

```
D:\LLVM\TestSource.cpp
```

its content is like:

```
void do_math(int *x) {
    *x += 5;
}

int main(void) {
    int result = -1, val = 4;
    do_math(&val);
    return result;
}
```

then in project properties,modify "Command Arguments" to:

```
"D:\LLVM\TestSource.cpp"
```

Then the project will build and debug successfully.

For debug/x64 configuration,modify project properties to:

include path:

```
D:\software\LLVM\clang\include;D:\software\LLVM\llvm\include;D:\software\LLVM\build-x64\include;D:\software\LLVM\build-x64\tools\clang\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

library path:

```
D:\software\LLVM\build-x64\Debug\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)
```

library(different from x86 library):

```
Mincore.lib;clangAnalysis.lib;clangARCMigrate.lib;clangAST.lib;clangASTMatchers.lib;clangBasic.lib;clangCodeGen.lib;clangCrossTU.lib;clangDriver.lib;clangDynamicASTMatchers.lib;clangEdit.lib;clangFormat.lib;clangFrontend.lib;clangFrontendTool.lib;clangHandleCXX.lib;clangIndex.lib;clangLex.lib;clangParse.lib;clangRewrite.lib;clangRewriteFrontend.lib;clangSema.lib;clangSerialization.lib;clangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.lib;clangStaticAnalyzerCore.lib;clangStaticAnalyzerFrontend.lib;clangTooling.lib;clangToolingASTDiff.lib;clangToolingCore.lib;clangToolingRefactor.lib;gtest.lib;libclang.lib;LLVMAArch64AsmParser.lib;LLVMAArch64AsmPrinter.lib;LLVMAArch64CodeGen.lib;LLVMAArch64Desc.lib;LLVMAArch64Disassembler.lib;LLVMAArch64Info.lib;LLVMAArch64Utils.lib;LLVMAMDGPUAsmParser.lib;LLVMAMDGPUAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMAMDGPUCodeGen.lib;LLVMAMDGPUDesc.lib;LLVMAMDGPUDisassembler.lib;LLVMAMDGPUInfo.lib;LLVMAMDGPUUtils.lib;LLVMAnalysis.lib;LLVMARMAsmParser.lib;LLVMARMAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMARMCodeGen.lib;LLVMARMDesc.lib;LLVMARMDisassembler.lib;LLVMARMInfo.lib;LLVMARMUtils.lib;LLVMAsmParser.lib;LLVMAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMBinaryFormat.lib;LLVMBitReader.lib;LLVMBitWriter.lib;LLVMBPFAsmParser.lib;LLVMBPFAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMBPFCodeGen.lib;LLVMBPFDesc.lib;LLVMBPFDisassembler.lib;LLVMBPFInfo.lib;LLVMCodeGen.lib;LLVMCore.lib;LLVMDebugInfoCodeView.lib;LLVMDebugInfoDWARF.lib;LLVMDebugInfoMSF.lib;LLVMDebugInfoPDB.lib;LLVMDemangle.lib;LLVMGlobalISel.lib;LLVMHexagonAsmParser.lib;LLVMHexagonCodeGen.lib;LLVMHexagonDesc.lib;LLVMHexagonDisassembler.lib;LLVMHexagonInfo.lib;LLVMInstCombine.lib;LLVMInstrumentation.lib;LLVMipo.lib;LLVMIRReader.lib;LLVMLanaiAsmParser.lib;LLVMLanaiAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMLanaiCodeGen.lib;LLVMLanaiDesc.lib;LLVMLanaiDisassembler.lib;LLVMLanaiInfo.lib;LLVMLinker.lib;LLVMMC.lib;LLVMMCDisassembler.lib;LLVMMCParser.lib;LLVMMipsAsmParser.lib;LLVMMipsAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMMipsCodeGen.lib;LLVMMipsDesc.lib;LLVMMipsDisassembler.lib;LLVMMipsInfo.lib;LLVMMSP430AsmPrinter.lib;LLVMMSP430CodeGen.lib;LLVMMSP430Desc.lib;LLVMMSP430Info.lib;LLVMNVPTXAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMNVPTXCodeGen.lib;LLVMNVPTXDesc.lib;LLVMNVPTXInfo.lib;LLVMObject.lib;LLVMOption.lib;LLVMPowerPCAsmParser.lib;LLVMPowerPCAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMPowerPCCodeGen.lib;LLVMPowerPCDesc.lib;LLVMPowerPCDisassembler.lib;LLVMPowerPCInfo.lib;LLVMProfileData.lib;LLVMScalarOpts.lib;LLVMSelectionDAG.lib;LLVMSparcAsmParser.lib;LLVMSparcAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMSparcCodeGen.lib;LLVMSparcDesc.lib;LLVMSparcDisassembler.lib;LLVMSparcInfo.lib;LLVMSupport.lib;LLVMSymbolize.lib;LLVMSystemZAsmParser.lib;LLVMSystemZAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMSystemZCodeGen.lib;LLVMSystemZDesc.lib;LLVMSystemZDisassembler.lib;LLVMSystemZInfo.lib;LLVMTableGen.lib;LLVMTarget.lib;LLVMTransformUtils.lib;LLVMVectorize.lib;LLVMX86AsmParser.lib;LLVMX86AsmPrinter.lib;LLVMX86CodeGen.lib;LLVMX86Desc.lib;LLVMX86Disassembler.lib;LLVMX86Info.lib;LLVMX86Utils.lib;LLVMXCoreAsmPrinter.lib;LLVMXCoreCodeGen.lib;LLVMXCoreDesc.lib;LLVMXCoreDisassembler.lib;LLVMXCoreInfo.lib;
```

disable specific warning:

```
4146
```

command  argument:

```
"D:\LLVM\TestSource.cpp"
```

The most important thing is you have to move the code

```
rewriter.getEditBuffer(rewriter.getSourceMgr().getMainFileID()).write(errs());
```

in the above reference from the main function to ExampleFrontendAction::EndSourceFileAction or there will be weird access exceptions.

Comment: Now it says "CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:45 (project):  Failed to run MSBuild command:" The workaround is to execute the cmake command under x86 or x64 native prompt of VS2017

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use Cmake to generate visual studio project files that you can then build with visual studio.
This tutorial shows you how it is done:
https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html

The part that you need is the paragraph https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#usage

Answer (score -1):

Using VisualGDB or applications like that, one can write code on Visual Studio and compile it on a linux machine. That is what I am doing right now.
I've installed clang on a linux virtual machine and in my windows 7 OS I have a Visual studio 2010. It works perfectly.